# Onclick Img tag and increment (between 1-10) and onclick other img and decrement (between 1-10) the same counter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, counter

Hello and Thanks for help!
I have this :

```
<div id="thumb1">
                <img class="img-responsive"  id="prova" src="img/thumb-up-dark.png" alt="">
                <div id="pinline">0</div>  
                <img class="img-responsive"  src="img/thumb-down-dark.png" alt="">
            </div>
```

And I have to increment the value in "pinline"  after every click untill 10;

I used this code:

```
$("#prova").click(function(){

    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('pinline').value, 10);
    value++;
    document.getElementById('pinline').innerHTML = value;
```

});

It returns "Nan". How can I do?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

It is not an input field, so you can't use `.value` here

Instead:

```
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('pinline').innerHTML, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks, which method I could use?

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your requirement completely

```
$("#prova").click(function(){

    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('pinline').innerHTML, 10);
    if(value < 10){
        value++;
        document.getElementById('pinline').innerHTML = value;
    }
});
```